# disable auto-prettier in react-native app

Tags: react-native, prettier

I'm using vim as my default editor which complains when some external tool changes the code while the buffer is open. I recently started working on a react-native app but every time i save the file it runs prettier in the background before pushing the app to the device, changing the files causing my vim to misbehave.

I initialized a default react-native app using

```
npx react-native init <project name>
```

I already had vim configured to run prettier on save but there is some external prettier run competing, and vim is losing. I can't find where this autolinting on save is configured anywhere in the files though.

Where can i disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following doc will give some solution for your problem

1. [Prettier and ESLint](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/modern-typescript-and-react-development-in-vim#prettier-and-eslint)
2. [Auto formatting](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/modern-typescript-and-react-development-in-vim#auto-formatting)